# Ajax only works when resending from firebug

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, firebug

```
$.post(
    "ajax.php",
    { action_do:"Register" },
    function(data,status){
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

This script is called when the form is submitted from a page, test.php. 
ajax.php just echo some text.

The response body from firebug refers to test.asp ???

If I right click on the resend inside of firebug, the ajax call works, and the response body is the text from ajax.php

I am puzzled.

Comment: Code seems fine. Please create a fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net that reproduces the error.

Comment: I am getting another error on fiddle but thats prob me.  I wrote the ajax call in javascript first and then jquery as I thought that it must be syntax